# Monitoring a process' message queue

Tags: monitoring, message-queue

Does anybody know of a good free program which can help me monitor the windows messages queued in a process' message queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WindowDetective seems to do the job!
http://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/